# Selecionar um RadioButton de um RadioGroup, de acordo com uma condição

Tags: android, radiobutton

Tenho um radiogroup e de acordo com uma condição deve ser selecionado um ou outro.
Como fazer com que ele suba à tela de acordo com o descrito abaixo?
Codigo:

```
private RadioGroup mSwitchButtonGroup;
private boolean mGoesByCar;
private User user;

    .....
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_confirm_routine, container, false);
                user = new User();
                mSwitchButtonGroup = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.switch_rider_button);

                if (user.hasCar()){
                    mSwitchButtonGroup -> R.id.goes_by_car deve aparecer checked
                }else {
                    mSwitchButtonGroup -> R.id.doesnt_go_by_car deve aparecer checked
                }
    ......

                if(mSwitchButtonGroup!=null){
                    mSwitchButtonGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            if(checkedId == R.id.goes_by_car){
                                mGoesByCar = true;
                            }else if(checkedId == R.id.doesnt_go_by_car){
                                mGoesByCar = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
....
```

Espero ter sido claro. Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método [check()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#check(int)) da classe [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html):

```
if (user.hasCar()){
    mSwitchButtonGroup.check(R.id.goes_by_car);
}else {
    mSwitchButtonGroup.check(R.id.doesnt_go_by_car)
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu já havia tentado dessa forma e não havia dado certo. Mas acabei descobrindo, depois q me deu a mesma resposta, que meu problema era na informação que eu busco do servidor... Novamente, obrigado!